# How to install Keil µVision on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, ide, embedded-system

I want to install Keil µVision on Ubuntu 18.04. How can I do that?

I would like to use Keil µVision for my laboratory microcontrollers and embedded systems.

Comment: It's 2022 and Keil MDK is still not officially supported on Linux(sigh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working for me.

1. Download [PlayOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux).
2. Download [Keil software for Windows](https://www.keil.com/download/) from their official website.
3. Open PlayOnLinux and install Keil µVision using *install a non-listed program* and choose the Keil executable file. After the installation open Keil µVision.

After that I have experienced two issues:

1. Could not open file.

   ```
   Error 56 can't open the file
   ```

   That was solved by rebuilding the project.
   Check the directory and rebuild the 
   project.
2. Some issues with memory mapping.

   ```
   *** Error 65: Access violation at 0x00000004 : No 'write' permission
   ```

   To solve this problem I created `MAP.ini` and placed this code inside 
   `MAP.ini` saved in `/home/usr/Desktop`. Then in Keil go to project 
   options: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> → Debug → Select the initialization file MAP.ini by 
   browsing to the specific folder.
   Put the code in MAP.ini without "": "MAP C:0x0000, C:0xFFFF read write exec"

[image: Keil Setup for MAP.ini File]

[image: Keil Screenshot1]

[image: Keil screenshot2]

**NOTE:Make sure your .asm or any other file including MAP.ini has permission read/write for other,group and owner**

Comment: I have updated the answer Check that!

Comment: Re. "To solve this problem I created MAP.ini and placed this code inside MAP.ini", what are the contents of MAP.ini? Are they in either image? Why not just post the contents as code/text instead of using images?

Comment: @PranuPranav Thank you for the update. However, it’s still not clear _what_ code did you put into the MAP.ini. Anyway, couldn’t both your issues be solved by properly setting file permissions?

Comment: I have updated the answers.

Comment: MAP C:0x0000, C:0xFFFF read write exec put this in map.ini

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this:

Download Keil Software from this [link](https://www.keil.com/download):

1. Install wine.
2. wine keilsetup.exe