# Embedded studio

Tags: c, linux-headers, embedded-system

I used to program embedded microcontrollers with keil uvision software on windows but recently I switched to ubuntu operating system and still don't know how to program microcontrollers (cortex -m3 series). I have researched and intend to use segger embedded studio software to do that but currently facing the problem that I do not know how to debug with st-link v2 on the software. Can anyone give me some advice?
https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/embedded-studio/

Comment: try this one https://askubuntu.com/a/1111866/856659

Comment: Possible native alternative is Mbed Studio from https://os.mbed.com/studio/ .

Answer (score 0):

From the question I deduce you are working with STM micros, they have [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) for example which is based on Java and thus works cross-platform.

Other useful tools include [STM32CubeProg](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) and [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing (2024-02), there are at least two official options:

- ST-LINK On-Board (old V2 versions) can be [converted into a J-Link](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/).
- Segger Embedded Studio since version 8 has [native ST-Link support](https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/embedded-studio/#native-st-link-support).